# Python 3 no write attribute?

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, pickle

I have an Error and below is part of the code:
The rest code is at https://github.com/Flajt/Python-Webcam/blob/Flajt-ui-1/ui.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Flajt\Documents\GitHub\Python-Webcam\ui.py", line 66, in <module>
    create()
  File "C:\Users\Flajt\Documents\GitHub\Python-Webcam\ui.py", line 31, in create
    save2=pickle.dump(password, hash)
TypeError: file must have a 'write' attribute`
```

Code:

```
if Pass_ok:
    hash = pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt(password2, rounds=200000, salt_size=16)
    password=open("pass.pkl","wb")
    save2=pickle.dump(password, hash)
    main()
```

Comment: its `dump(hash, password)`. `help(pickle.dump)` helps!

Comment: @tdlaney in my script is a write attribute (I think so)

Comment: The signature is `dump(obj, file, protocol=None, *, fix_imports=True)` that is, you do the thing you want to pickle first, and the file you want to pickle it into second.

Comment: @tdlaney thanks so much and a last Question can  I make something like global with funktions; and can i Vote you up and close the Question?

Comment: I'll post an answer. I'm not sure what you mean about the globals... can you rephrase that? or post a new question with an example? BTW, `pickle.dump` doesn't return anything useful, so with  `save2=pickle.dump(...)` `save2` is always `None`.

Comment: @tdleaney like variables i can use it in a function and with the global command I can use it everywere in the script (in my comment bevor i miss a how after the  ;  )

Comment: You can use the `global` keyword inside functions. For instance `global foo` inside a function means that when `foo` is used inside that function, it is `foo` in the module-global namespace. It only applies to the function it is used in.

Comment: that i know but i want to run a funktion that i define bevor i call it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was simply that you reversed the two parameters to `pickle.dump`. As an aside, its best to write a short, running, demonstration script when you can. That way others can run it easily. Here's a runnable solution with the fix

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pickle
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256

hash = pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt("foo", rounds=200000, salt_size=16)
with open("pass.pkl", "wb") as password:
    # save2=pickle.dump(password, hash)
    pickle.dump(hash, password)
```